# Different meanings of 'an algebra'?

Tags: reference-request, definition

I am slightly confused about the definition of an algebra. Depending on the context the definitions seem to vary widely. For **example** [this source](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ecwalkden/ergodic-theory/lecture08.pdf) in the context of measure theory defines an algebra as follows:

> A collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is called an *algebra*
> if:
>
> 1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$,
> 2. if $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B\in \mathcal{A}$;
> 3. if $A\in \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c\in \mathcal{A}$.

whilst (Dummit and Foote, 2004;pg342) define an algebra as follows:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. An $R$-*algebra* is a
> ring $A$ with identity together with a ring homomorphism
> $f:R\rightarrow A$ mapping $1_R$ to $1_A$ such that the subring $f(R)$
> of $A$ is contained in the center of $A$.

Clearly these two **examples** are very different. As such is there a overall definition of an *algebra* which includes all such definitions (i.e. if $A$ is an algebra under one of these then it will be an algebra under the overall definition)? If not does anyone know of any source that lists the definitions of 'an algebra' in different contexts?

Comment: I don't know about the origin of the term, but certainly the first one forms a ring with symmetric difference and intersection ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986529/power-set-of-x-is-a-ring-with-symmetric-difference-and-intersection ) and hence, an algebra over itself.

Comment: At first a $k$-algebra $A$ is what you need to consider polynomials $\sum_{n=0}^d c_n a^n$ with coefficients $c_n \in k$ and $a \in A$. An algebra of sets becomes a boolean algebra (algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$) when you consider the addition $a \oplus b = \{ x \in a, x \not \in b\} \cup \{x \in b, x \not\in a\}$ (termwise xor). The union of sets $a \cup b$ is not an addition, but infinite union and intersection have certain good properties, allowing some sort of completions like $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 1):

## General Definition of an Algebra

In general we can define an algebra as follows (from {1;pg2}, verbatim):

> An **algebra** is an ordered pair $\langle A,F\rangle$ such that $A$
> is a nonempty set and $F=\langle F_i: i \in I\rangle$ where $F_i$ is a
> finitary operation on $A$ for each $i\in I$. $A$ is called the
> **universe** of $\langle A, F\rangle$, $F_i$ is refereed to as a **fundamental** or **basic operation** of $\langle A,F \rangle$ for each $i \in I$, and $I$ is called the **index set** or the **set of
> operation symbols** of $\langle A,F\rangle$.

(emphasis not mine).

## Terminology

Definition 1 above is actually defining an **algebra of sets** rather then  a general algebra whilst definition 2 is defining an **$R$-algebra** where $R$ is a ring.

## References

{1} [http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/ALVin.pdf](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Eralph/Classes/619/ALVin.pdf)